# Facing issue, when serenity js library is included for Cucumber protractor typescript tests

Tags: protractor, cucumber, serenity-bdd

I am learning Cucumber BDD with serenity js library for reporting purpose off Angular website . I am using Type script as programming language.

I am able to generate the cucumber report for different feature file scenarios.  But when i am trying to include the serenity library for report enhancement, i am facing the below issue. -

Issue is :

```
PS R:\protractor\protractor-cucumber-typescript> tsc
PS R:\protractor\protractor-cucumber-typescript> npm test

> protractor-typescript-cucumber@3.0.0 pretest R:\protractor\protractor-cucumber-typescript
> serenity update

info: Serenity BDD CLI jar file is up to date :-)

> protractor-typescript-cucumber@3.0.0 test R:\protractor\protractor-cucumber-typescript
> protractor typeScript/config/config.js

[15:29:46] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[15:29:46] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
[15:29:54] E/launcher - Error: TypeError: Path must be a string. Received true
    at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
    at Object.basename (path.js:801:5)
    at R:\protractor\protractor-cucumber-typescript\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber\cli\configuration.js:11:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function.Configuration (R:\protractor\protractor-cucumber-typescript\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber\cli\configuration.js:10:10)
    at getConfiguration (R:\protractor\protractor-cucumber-typescript\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber\cli.js:63:38)
    at Object.run (R:\protractor\protractor-cucumber-typescript\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber\cli.js:69:27)
    at R:\protractor\protractor-cucumber-typescript\node_modules\serenity-js\src\serenity-cucumber\cucumber_test_framework.ts:24:51
    at CucumberTestFramework.run (R:\protractor\protractor-cucumber-typescript\node_modules\serenity-js\src\serenity-cucumber\cucumber_test_framework.ts
:21:16)
    at R:\protractor\protractor-cucumber-typescript\node_modules\serenity-js\src\serenity-protractor\framework\serenity_protractor_framework.ts:52:35
[15:29:54] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Its not giving any traces of the files i have. Its showing me a different file.

### Serenity dependency got downloaded, But  when the protractor conf.js file run. I am getting above issue

Files look like below -

Conf.ts file looks like below  :

```
   import * as path from "path";
import { browser, Config } from "protractor";
const crew = require('serenity-js/lib/stage_crew');

export const config: Config = {

    seleniumAddress: "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub",
    SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
    // baseUrl: "http://www.google.com",
    baseUrl2: "https://angularjs.org/",

    framework: "custom",
    frameworkPath: require.resolve('serenity-js'),
    specs: [
        "../../features/*Home.feature",
    ],
    cucumberOpts: {
      //  require: ["../../stepdefinitions/*.ts","../../support/stepdefinitions/*.js"],
        require: ["stepdefinitions/*/**.ts","support/stepdefinitions/*/**.js"],
     //   strict: true,
        format: "pretty",
        compiler: "ts:ts-node/register",
    },
    serenity: {
        dialect: 'cucumber',
        crew: [
            crew.serenityBDDReporter(),
            crew.photographer(),
            crew.consoleReporter()
        ]
    },
    capabilities: {
        browserName: "chrome",
    },
    onPrepare: () => {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.manage().window().maximize();
        browser.get("https://angularjs.org/");
    },
};
```

My package.json file looks like below :

```
{
  "name": "protractor-typescript-cucumber",
  "keywords": [
    "protractor",
    "cucumber",
    "typescript",
    "angular",
    "angularjs",
    "testing",
    "behaviour driven development",
    "bdd",
    "selenium",
    "webdriverJS",
    "gherkin",
    "automation testing"
  ],
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "clean": "rimraf typeScript/",
    "clean-build": "npm run clean && npm run build",
    "test": "protractor typeScript/config/config.js",
    "webdriver-update": "webdriver-manager update",
    "webdriver-start": "webdriver-manager start",
    "pretest": "serenity update",
    "report": "serenity run"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cucumber": "^2.0.4",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.3",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "^3.0.7",
    "chai": "^4.0.2",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.0.0",
    "chai-smoothie": "^0.3.2",
    "cucumber": "1.3.2",
    "cucumber-html-reporter": "^3.0.4",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "protractor": "^5.1.2",
    "protractor-cucumber": "^0.1.8",
    "protractor-cucumber-framework": "^4.0.8",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "serenity-cli": "^0.2.4",
    "serenity-js": "^1.4.1",
    "standard-loader": "^6.0.1",
    "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^2.5.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.0.4"
  }
}
```

Please update me, where i am going wrong

Comment: Hi. this is the author of `protractor-cucumber-typescript` your error says it all, in your `cucumberOpts` object you are setting `path` to be true which accepts a string not a boolean value, use of path option is redundant as you are specifying the feature file path in `specs` option.

Comment: Hi Ram, i have updated the conf.js file. Now its working fine.

And by the way, you have wonderful repo - for the explanation of the Protractor cucumber frame work. I have implemented yours and enhanced it. its working fine.  Thank you so much yar.

Comment: Along with the path condition. i have n't mentioned the js files of Step definitions. After changing them. It worked.